# Puppeteer SetViewPort in Gologin or AdsPower Browsers, change creepJS browser fingerprint

Tags: macos, puppeteer, fingerprint, gologin

Hello like in topic when I use puppeteer without setViewPort and manually without puppeteer, browser lands in 66% of creepjs test, but when do automation via puppeteer to visit creepJS, it land on 44-54%, and I cant figure out why, what happens when set viewport.

Here code:

```
  const profileID = await adsPower.createNewProfile(proxy[0]);
  //const wsEndpoint = await adsPower.startBrowser('jcmw3p5')
  const wsEndpoint = await adsPower.startBrowser(profileID.id)
  let browser = await puppeteer.connect({
    browserWSEndpoint: wsEndpoint,
    defaultViewport: { width: 1512, height: 949 }
  });

  const pages = await browser.pages();
  const page = pages[0];

  // await page.setViewport({
  //   width: 1512,
  //   height: 949,
  //   deviceScaleFactor: 1,
  // });

  await page.goto('https://abrahamjuliot.github.io/creepjs/')
```

Here I upload test with puppeteer vs manual/without setviewport function
[IMAGE: left puppeteer, right manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vOGG.jpg)

Comment: Right--you're automating so isn't it expected that it's less trustworthy? For starters, the default user agent is "I am a robot" for Puppeteer, and I don't see that you've changed it in your code. You're also running headlessly, which usually makes the automation easier to detect. In any case, do you have an actual problem caused by the lower percentage, like a particular site blocking you?

Comment: headless is false, I use gologin. So why when go to site via puppeteer without setviewport its same like on right? but change viewport it change score?

Comment: I think I understand what you're asking. Checking the viewport for certain characteristics and monitoring changes is a common bot detection technique, although I don't know the technical details. Why do you want to set the viewport? I almost always just leave it default.

Comment: Ive tested default too, but I was deteceted when captcha solving, 1img for 5-10mins, then 10 img, so searching what forced this higher images to solve

Comment: The viewport isn't the only thing that's used for detection, so using the default viewport increases your chances of success but doesn't guarantee it. If you're asking because you're actually trying to do something, I suggest [asking about that thing directly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676).